# What is an HM Slave?

Tags: terminology, pokemon-series

I just came across the term "HM Slave" in reference to a Pokemon character.  A couple of questions [such as this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/26408/5398) reference the term but I haven't been able to find anything that defines it.

**What is an HM Slave?**

Comment: How did you not find a definition? There are dozens of results in a quick Google search. Although it includes this question now, so it doesn't matter ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Though the necessity varies between generations and games, the general idea is that, especially late in the game, you cannot reach certain areas without some of the HM moves: i.e., strength, cut, surf, whirlpool, dive, etc. (Again, the actual requirements vary by game).

An HM slave, then, is a term for a pokemon that is not used for battle but knows one or more of these moves, such that the battle performance of your other 5 pokemon is not diminished by "wasting" one of your 4 attack moves with an HM move (which are generally subpar compared to other, similar, options).

Comment: Examples of ideal HM Slave pokemon species include Kingler, Linoone, Bibarel, and so on.

Comment: And, of course, Mew.

Comment: And in gen 2, Gyrados could learn Surf, Waterfall, Whirlpool, and I believe it could even learn Strength.