# How can I effectively use Exp. Share to EV train my Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

Related to [my previous question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/134240/9350), I am interested in the specifics of the new Exp. Share.

When using it to EV train Pokemon, do all Pokemon in the party gain the base EVs for the Pokemon defeated? Do Pokemon holding an EV-effecting item such as Macho Braces or Power items still gain the effects of those items even if they never actually see battle?

Comment: They definitely get the EVs. Unsure about the EV affecting items, but I assume yes. Will let someone test to be sure

Answer (score 5):

When using EXP Share, the EV gain is applied to all your Pokemon *that gain EXP*, so fainted Pokemon will not receive EVs. Pokemon that are holding EV-gain items like Macho Brace or the Power series will received the appropriate increased EVs even if they aren't switched in.

Comment: Have you read this or confirmed through experimentation?

Comment: Confirmed. Pokerus also doubles EV gain, after modifiers like Macho Brace and Power items have been taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, whatever base EVs that would be gained from the lead battler will be passed through the EXP share to any non-fainted pokemon.  If any pokemon in your party have Pokerus, those EV gains are doubled ONLY ON THAT POKEMON.  If Lead pokemon and lead pokemon only has pokerus, the party pokemon will not gain the extra EV boosts from it.  Same goes with EV boosting items: they affect those that are holding them