# EV training with EXP.SHARE in Omega Ruby

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

I EV trained by defeating hordes of Zigzagoon about 70 times. My party consisted of a few Pokémon without any experience after being caught. The lead Pokémon was an EV-maxed Pokémon and the EXP.SHARE was turned on.

After one of the Pokémon leveled up, it only gained 3 speed stat points. Is this normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: **Yes**. So long as the other Pokemon in your party were not fainted, [they gain the full EV effects of whatever the lead Pokemon defeated when EXP.SHARE is turned on](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/136956/how-can-i-effectively-use-exp-share-to-ev-train-my-pokemon).

Per [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Statistic#In_Generation_III_onward), The formula that determines your stats is:

```
HP = ((((2 * BASE + IV + (EV / 4)) * LEVEL) / 100) + LEVEL + 10)
Other Stats = (((((2 * BASE + IV + (EV / 4)) * LEVEL) / 100) + 5) * Nature)
```

What this effectively means is that the total bonus Effort Values provide is distributed out across all 100 levels. You don't get the whole value all at once, it is metered out until the full value is reached at lvl 100.

If you trained speed to 200EVs (+50 to speed), in addition whatever speed it would normally gain every level - every second level that value is effectively raised by 1. It isn't very noticeable on any given level up, but over the course of several levels it starts to add up.

Comment: While it's pretty unnoticeable for a low-level Pokémon, I remember one time I focus trained EVs on a freshly caught Azelf in Gen 4, which started at level 50, so when it first leveled up, it gained something like 30 Speed points. XP

Comment: @MikeKellogg I believe this may depend on the generation; for example in the past you could EV train a lvl 100 Pokemon, but you had to deposit and withdraw it from a PC Box before the stats would change to reflect the EVs. I think in recent games, stat changes due to EVs are updated far more dynamically.