# EV training not working?

Tags: pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green

I hatched a Gastly egg, with average stats and a Mild nature. I trained it with Exp. Share to about level 50 and evolved it to Haunter. With the Haunter I went EV training in the Pokémon Tower, killing Gastly and Haunter for Special Attack, and then Diglett and Dugtrio in Diglett's Cave for Speed. My Haunter always wore a Macho Brace. After I was sure I killed enough Pokémon, I finished up by killing 4 Caterpie for HP. Then I evolved it to a Gengar by trading and leveled it to Lv. 100 by killing Machoke and stuff.

Now the Final Stats:

- Gengar (female)
- Nature = Mild
- Hp. 247
- Atk. 223
- Def. 121
- SpA. 387
- SpD. 173
- Spe. 248

So, my question is: was it just not working, or are my IVs really that bad?

Comment: "Pokemon holding an Exp. Share will also gain EVs even if they don't participate in the battle." Assuming I'm reading what you did right, leveling it up to 50 first got it a bunch of random EVs before you even started EV training.

Comment: @MikeKellogg is correct, and [supported by this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/136956/how-can-i-effectively-use-exp-share-to-ev-train-my-pokemon#136970). I believe the same is true in FRLG with EV distribution. Any Pokemon that gains exp gains the EVs as well. Your power leveling probably gave it some undesired EVs off the bat.

Comment: Further support: [this calculator](http://veekun.com/dex/gadgets/stat_calculator?effort=4%2C0%2C0%2C252%2C0%2C252&stat=247%2C223%2C121%2C387%2C173%2C248&level=100&pokemon=%40us%2Cpokemon_species%3AGengar&nature=mild) shows that the stats you named are impossible for any IV values for Attack and Speed. You got a bunch of Attack EVs during the leveling to 50, and never got any Speed EVs worth mentioning.

Comment: F*ck! That really renders the Exp. Share 100% useless! That makes me a little bit angry... but at least the SpA training worked... Thanks Guys!

Comment: Eh, since I basically answered the question anyway, throwing what I said into an actual answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Your EV training failed because Pokémon still receive EVs through the Exp. Share

Leveling the Gastly up to level 50 using the Exp. Share caused it to still receive the EVs from whatever Pokémon were defeated, even if they don't participate in the battle. [This calculator](http://veekun.com/dex/gadgets/stat_calculator?effort=4%2C0%2C0%2C252%2C0%2C252&stat=247%2C223%2C121%2C387%2C173%2C248&level=100&pokemon=%40us%2Cpokemon_species%3AGengar&nature=mild) shows that your Attack and Speed stats are impossible for any IV values for the EV training you were attempting to do, with Attack being too high and Speed being too low, implying that Gastly received a number of Attack EVs during the leveling up process, and thus was maxed out on EVs when you attempted to start training Speed. You may also have ended up collecting a small number of EVs in other stats, depending on which Pokémon you battled.